# React Bootstrap Components not showing when deployed to Heroku

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, react-bootstrap, mern

I have this project working on localHost without any issues I belive its due to the console errors:

```
The stylesheet https://fcclibaryproject.herokuapp.com/static/css/2.de424728.chunk.css was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/html", is not "text/css". fcclibaryproject.herokuapp.com
The stylesheet https://fcclibaryproject.herokuapp.com/static/css/main.5deba5b1.chunk.css was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/html", is not "text/css". fcclibaryproject.herokuapp.com
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
2.bcc2d95b.chunk.js:1
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
main.b2182094.chunk.js:1
```

​heres a link to the react app: https://fcclibaryproject.herokuapp.com/

This is only the second time ive depolyed an app to anywhere but I think the above is an error with react bootstrap not loading its Components and hence the screen being blank.
To use react bootstrap I c/p the CDN link into the index.html which may be where the error is as the page is being served though express, but im not sure what im ment to do to fix this.

the express/mongo api works fine and according to the heroku logs react is loaded.

Comment: Because your javascript bundle is not being sent properly. That's why instead of js code, they have index.html code.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply! im sending the static page from /client/build extactly the same way i did for my other project. 
i appreciate the responce but im not sure where i should go from here, the index.html was being served for my last project to have the react app rendering into it

Comment: If I am not wrong, I believe somewhere you have written a script, where on any file request from the browser to the server, you are sending only index.html file.

Comment: yes i had to add an app.use so the app got severed correctly thanks alot for your help!